# Recovery bootable partition

Tags: live-usb, data-recovery

How to create a partition on my hard drive containing Ubuntu/Windows ISO files so i don't have to create flash drives every time i screw something up? The point of the partition is to keep my iso files so i can boot and install/reinstall both OS-es from there. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It's also relatively easy. I have done it and can confirm it works. Here's my procedure (this is assuming your computer is UEFI compatible, and that you have a UEFI boot menu):

1. Download the ISO for the version of Ubuntu you want.
2. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`.
3. Install `Gparted` if you haven't already: `sudo apt-get install gparted`.
4. Open `Gparted` by searching for it in Dash or running `gparted` in the terminal.
5. Let `Gparted` scan your drives.
6. Select a partition on your hard drive that you are willing to downsize by about 8GB.
7. Right-click that partition and select the `Resize/Move` option.
8. In the `MiB After` field, enter `8192` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> before hitting <kbd>OK</kbd>.
9. Format the partition as `FAT32`. Feel free to label the partition something like "UbuntuLive".
10. Click the green check button toward the top of the `Gparted` window apply the resize and creation.
11. Let `Gparted` scan your drives again, and take note of the new partition's number (it will look something like `/dev/sdXY`). Close `Gparted`.
12. Once you're done with partitioning, search for `Unetbootin` in the Dash, or open it from the terminal by running `unetbootin`.
13. Once `Unetbootin` has opened, select the second option in it. (Something like "Use an ISO file").
14. Browse to your downloaded ISO and select it. (Go to `Computer>>/home/username/Downloads`)
15. There should be a dropdown in Unetbootin that has `USB Drive` currently selected. Change that to `Hard Drive`.
16. To the right of that, there should be another dropdown with a list of partitions. Select the one you created in `Gparted`.
17. Click the button near the bottom right to confirm your settings and "burn" the ISO to the partition.

Now you should be able to reboot, go into your computer's boot menu, and see something like `UEFI OS`, or, if your computer is more featured, the actual name of the partition (UbuntuLive). Just select that to boot into an Ubuntu Live environment from your hard drive.

If your computer isn't UEFI capable, comment that, and I'll edit in a second set of instructions.

If any of the instructions confuse you, leave a comment, and I'll help walk you through the process.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for the simple solution!

Comment: Great! If you're at all like me, it'll come in handy quite a bit.

Comment: I reinstall every 1-2 days. It WILL be priceless

Comment: How do I do it with windows iso?

Comment: @FixXxeR Make another 8GB FAT32 partition and copy the contents of the Windows ISO into that partition. You should be able to boot into it from the UEFI menu again.